# TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file in Magento2

Tags: magento2, base-url, paths, invoice-pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to get PDF Download able, I installed TCPDF library by this:

```
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf
```

and created PDF Document as:

// create new PDF document

```
$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Then created this function in block for testing and called in template:

```
public function testPdf(){

    $tcpdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $tcpdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

    $tcpdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');

    $tcpdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');

    $tcpdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');

    $tcpdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');


// set default header data

    $Header_title = 'Sample PDF';

    $tcpdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE . $Header_title, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0, 64, 255), array(0, 64, 128));

    $tcpdf->setFooterData(array(0, 64, 0), array(0, 64, 128));


// set header and footer fonts

    $tcpdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

    $tcpdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));


// set default monospaced font

    $tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


// set margins

    $tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

    $tcpdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

    $tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


// set auto page breaks

    $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


// set image scale factor

    $tcpdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// set some language-dependent strings (optional)

    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {

        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');

        $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    }


// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode

    $tcpdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

//your htmls here

$html = '<h1> hello world </h1>';

// set some language dependent data:

    $lg = Array();

    $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';


    $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($lg);


// set font

//dejavusans & freesans For Indian Rupees symbol

    $tcpdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);

    // remove default header/footer

//$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

    $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


    $tcpdf->AddPage();


    $tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


    $tcpdf->lastPage();



//$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

    $this->logger->debug('report_per_route');
    $baseurl = $this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl();
    $filename = $baseurl . 'Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';
    $tcpdf->Output($filename, 'F');
    //$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route_'.time().'.pdf', 'I');

}
```

And geting this error:

```
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: http://localhost/magento_15/Sample_pdf1539345194.pdf
```

This error is due to baseurl as I firstly i was having this variable's error as undefined and then I asighn it localhost baseurl as seen in error.

If i do this with last part:

```
//$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

    $this->logger->debug('report_per_route');
    //$baseurl = $this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl();
    //$filename = $baseurl . 'Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';
    //$tcpdf->Output($filename, 'F');
    $tcpdf->Output('report_per_route_'.time().'.pdf', 'I');
```

then this happens:
[image]

if do this with last part:

```
//$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

    $this->logger->debug('report_per_route');
    $baseurl = $this->_urlInterface->getDirPath();
    $filename = $baseurl . 'Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';
    $tcpdf->Output($filename, 'F');
    //$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route_'.time().'.pdf', 'I');
```

Then this warning comes:

[image]

how it should be handled rightly? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please use absolute path

Comment: thanks @Abdul for reply, which is absolute path ?

Comment: Try this : $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
    $this->logger->debug('report_per_route');
    $filename = $mediaPath . 'Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';
    $tcpdf->Output($filename, 'F');

Comment: Getting this error now: Notice: Undefined variable: fileSystem in E:\Xampp\htdocs\magento_15\app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Order.php on line 141

Comment: I was able to successfully achieve it by this way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251287/67038