# How to install TCPDF lib without composer in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, installation, 3rd-party-library, tcpdf

Followed these steps:

1. Download TCPDF from https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf
2. Change the name of the file root directory after extraction to TCPDF
3. Inside this directory, there is a tcpdf.php file, change the name to TCPDF
4. Open the file and change the class name from tcpdf to TCPDF_TCPDF
5. Copy the files into your Magento “lib” folder in the root Magento installation directory. i.e lib/TCPDF

   And can be called this class by $tcpdf = new TCPDF_TCPDF() from anywhere in Magento. [Here is Source](https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/using-tcpdf-with-magento.html)

But this is not working!!
Getting Error like: Fatal error:

> Class 'Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Generatepdf\TCPDF_TCPDF' not
>   found in
>   E:\Xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Generatepdf\CreatePdf.php
>   on line 35

Installation with composer works fine and I get PDF generated! But I have to send this complete package and cannot ask client to run composer command for this module.I think autoloader is not getting aware of this library. How can I integrate it?

This is my class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Generatepdf;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class CreatePdf extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  {

protected $_dir;
protected $customerName;
protected $order;
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Order $order,
    DirectoryList $dir

)
{
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->_dir = $dir;

    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {

     $tcpdf = new TCPDF_TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    //$tcpdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $tcpdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

    $tcpdf->SetTitle('Title');

    $tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

    $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


    // set default monospaced font

    $tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


    // set margins

    $tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

    $tcpdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

    $tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


    // set auto page breaks

    $tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


    // set image scale factor

    $tcpdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)

    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {

        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');

        $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set default font subsetting mode

    $tcpdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

    //your htmls here

    $html=$this->getHtml();

    // set some language dependent data:

    $lg = Array();

    $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';


    $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($lg);


    // set font

    //dejavusans & freesans For Indian Rupees symbol

    $tcpdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);

    // remove default header/footer

    //$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

    $tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


    $tcpdf->AddPage();


    $tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


    $tcpdf->lastPage();

    //$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

    //$this->logger->debug('report_per_route');
    $baseurl = $this->getDirPath();
    $filename = $baseurl .'/export/'. 'Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';
    $tcpdf->Output($filename, 'I');
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the successfully tested way to do this:

1. Download TCPDF from https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf
2. Change the name of the file root directory after extraction to TCPDF
3. Inside this directory, there is a tcpdf.php file, change the name to TCPDF
4. Open the file and change the class name from tcpdf to TCPDF_TCPDF
5. Copy the files into your Magento “lib/internal” folder in the root Magento installation directory.

=>So it should look like this: lib/internal/TCPDF

Now, write below statement in the class where you want to make tcpdf object:

```
require_once('lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php');
```

And use this class as:

```
$tcpdf = new \TCPDF_TCPDF();
```

Example Code is:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Generatepdf;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

require_once('lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php');

class CreatePdf extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  {

protected $_dir;
protected $customerName;
protected $order;
public function __construct(
Context $context,
Order $order,
DirectoryList $dir

)
{
$this->order = $order;
$this->_dir = $dir;

parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {

$tcpdf = new \TCPDF_TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$tcpdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

$tcpdf->SetTitle('Title');

$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

$tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


// set default monospaced font

$tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


// set margins

$tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

$tcpdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

$tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


// set auto page breaks

$tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


// set image scale factor

$tcpdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// set some language-dependent strings (optional)

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');

    $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($l);

}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode

$tcpdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

//your htmls here

$html=$this->getHtml();

// set some language dependent data:

$lg = Array();

$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';


$tcpdf->setLanguageArray($lg);


// set font

//dejavusans & freesans For Indian Rupees symbol

$tcpdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);

// remove default header/footer

//$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

$tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


$tcpdf->AddPage();


$tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


$tcpdf->lastPage();

//$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

//$this->logger->debug('report_per_route');
$baseurl = $this->getDirPath();
$filename = $baseurl .'/export/'. 'Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';
$tcpdf->Output($filename, 'I');
}

}
?>
```

Happy coding :)