# Mahento 2: How to incldue third party Library in package for sending to client installed by composer?

Tags: magento2, autoloader, lib

I have installed a library (TCPDF) by composer and it is working fine, but I need to send full package for client. How can I add library without composer?

I followed [this](https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/using-tcpdf-with-magento.html) but autoloader is not getting aware of the library by [this](https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/using-tcpdf-with-magento.html) way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by this way:

[How to install TCPDF lib without composer in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250951/how-to-install-tcpdf-lib-without-composer-in-magento-2)

It was quit simple but tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use composer require tecnick.com/tcpdf to solve this problem. 
TCPDF is a PHP class for generating PDF documents and barcodes. More information is there https://packagist.org/packages/tecnick.com/tcpdf

Comment: Thanks @BeIVG for reply. The issue is solved, look at my answer.